# Angular 2 forms version?

Tags: forms, angular, npm

In going to the **Angular 2.0.0-rc.4** 5 Minute Quickstart tutorial.

The `package.json` has the following line:

```
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
```

However, when I run my app, I'm getting the following warning:

> It looks like you're using the old forms module. This will be opt-in in the next RC, and will eventually be removed in favor of the new forms module.

Is there a different forms `NPM` that I'm supposed to be using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the old forms API is undergoing a deprecation phase. From the docs:

> The old forms API is going through a deprecation phase. During this
> transition Angular is supporting both form modules.
>
> To remind us that the old API is deprecated, Angular will print a warning message to the console.
>
> Since we are converting to the new API, and no longer need the old API, we call disableDeprecatedForms() to disable the old form
> functionality and the warning message.
>
> ...
>
> To use this API, you must opt in by adding special providers to your bootstrap file (see the [Bootstrap section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#bootstrap) below).

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html